# Load webpage from different domain

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cors

I am creating a sample project in MVC.
Suppose I have two projects A and B.
In project A I have a javascript file which takes index page of `project A`  and put it in a div having id `Widget`.

In `project B` index page I have a reference to the javascript file of project A and a div with id `Widget`.

On page load I want to load `Project A's index page` to `Project B's Widget Div`.

Here is my code

```
Project A

Index.cshtml (Index view)

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}  
<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="data">Thi is index page.</div>

Widget.js (JavaScript file)

$(document).ready(function (e) {
$('#widget').load('/Home/Contact', function (response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
};
```

Here is another project

```
Project B

Index view which call the project A's index view
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2455/Scripts/Widget.js"></script>

<div id="widget"></div>

<div>Project B Index</div>
```

Above sample code display index view of Project B while I want to display index view of Project A

Comment: your url '/Home/Contact' is local, you should to add full url to project A index controller.

Comment: If I add full url then `CORS issue` occurs

Comment: Without full url it will not work the way you want. To enable cross domain request you need to add 2 headers to your web.configs 

`<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="access-control-allow-headers" value="content-type"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
<system.webServer>`

Or the other way is in your Contact controller of calss B to make http request to controller of class A, then you will get HTML of controller of calss without CORS issue.

Comment: Sorry, request from Project B to project A and not class.

Comment: thnx your solution worked for me I can mark it as answer if you post the same in the answer. Also can you show me any example for second option (make http request to controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without full url it will not work the way you want. To enable cross domain request you need to add 2 headers to your web.configs 

    `<system.webServer> 
        <httpProtocol> 
            <customHeaders> 
                <add name="access-control-allow-headers" value="content-type"/> 
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/> 
            </customHeaders> 
       </httpProtocol> 
    <system.webServer>`

Or the other way is in your Contact controller of project B to make http request to controller of project A, then you will get HTML of controller of project A without CORS issue

The second solution is

1. Make request to the local controller
2. In the local controller call to the code bellow, this code makes request to some url and returns all that retrieved from the url.

   `var html = "";
   StreamReader reader = null;
   WebResponse response = null;
   try
   {
         var request = WebRequest.Create("url of project A controller");
         response = request.GetResponse();
         var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
         reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
         //here you will get HTML of controller from project A
         html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    finally
    {
         if (reader != null)
         {
             reader.Close();
         }
         if (response != null)
         {
              response.Close();
         }
     }
   ViewBag.HTML = html;//And then you can use the HTML inside of current controller, simply put    @ViewBag.HTML inside of the div.`

Comment: is there any javascript or jquery equivalent code for the same?

Comment: your solution worked for me thnx..no need of jquery code